# ax 2012 - dial functionality in smmContactPerson

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

is it possible to implement the dial functionality from the smmContactPerson (ContactInfoGrid - CommTypeIcon) in the smmContactsListPage grid?

The problem is that i can add a column to the grid, but can NOT add the mouseup-event (because the form is a ListPage). Is there a way to get the mouseUp event work? Maybe in the corresponding interaction class?

Thanks in advance,

Frank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think mouse events can be monitored by the interaction class.

What about using a good old button?

Comment: Hi Jan,
thanks for answering. Of course i could place a button in the Action pane - but i can't add any events (like "clicked" or something). And in any other place it is IMHO not possible to place a button...

I was wondering if there is a "nicer" (in the grid) solution :).

Frank

Comment: And the answer was no.

Comment: To expand from Jan I would think best practice would be to put a call button on the ActionPane which calls the current record, maybe use the interaction class to enable/disable depending on a phone number existing for the contact?